# How to upload a file by using file upload control without upload button?

Tags: asp.net

I just wanted to upload multiple files at once with out any upload button. That is, let's consider that I am using file upload control. So after browse file when I will click on ok button then automatically it will upload.

Comment: you can do this with jquery. u would like to upload a file like gmail. is it?

Comment: Yes, something like that...
Can you please let me know with one example?

Answer (score 1):

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa478971

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in this upload file button used. I am saying without that how to do ?

Comment: Then this might be better http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in local area network , and using Windows 7, you have to set  the identity of  pool aplication in IIS  to networkService